# Twilio issue when sending message with German character

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm using Twilio to send an SMS message. However, the message is not displayed properly on the mobile devices with German text. For example, the message is "Grüße" but the character "ü" and "ß" is not displayed correctly like this: [image]

The issue happen on both Java SDK and cURL with REST. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Open a ticket via the Twilio console to report this issue, along with the Messaging SID(s) experiencing the issue, so they can determine what is causing the problem.

Also, indicate your troubleshooting steps above (Java/cURL), which is important information as well.